# Updating an grid of "players" by replacing losers with copies of the winner

Tags: algorithm

I have a two-dimensional array of objects. Each object has, at all times, some (variable) score (i.e. an object's score at time t is not necessarily the object's score at time t+1). I want to find the most efficient algorithm which will duplicate any object with a greater score than its neighbour, and place that duplicate into the neighbour's place.<sup>1</sup>

My first impulse was the naive solution:

- Create a copy of the array
- set "changeWasMade" flag to false
- cycle through all positions p

  - compare scores with all neighbours n
  - if score(p) > score(n), replace n in the copied grid with a copy of p and set "changeWasMade" to true
- if "changeWasMade", then discard original grid, and repeat using the copy as the new original; else, return the copy

However, for an n x n array, this seems to be O(n<sup>4</sup>) (n<sup>2</sup> possible iterations of n<sup>2</sup> checks), which seems pretty slow to me. Since my algorithmic knowledge is pretty poor, I thought it would be wise to ask if there's a quicker way to do this.

*UPDATE*

It's just occurred to me that it might be quicker to make one "pass" of replacements, and then to check that all newly created (i.e. cloned) objects have the highest score of their neighbours (i.e. are a local maximum). If they are, great, the right thing has happened - if they're not, then replace them with a copy of the neighbour with the highest score. This will probably cut down on required iterations (though it will require some good book-keeping to keep everything straight!) - is there still a quicker method?

** Footnotes**

1. (For some context, for those who have read "The Quantum Thief", this is the setup of the prison described in the opening pages)

Comment: The algorithm is O(n2), which means each object is operated on once each iteration. The constant is determined by the time it takes to find the highest score out of 5 plus the cost of copying an object. I think it would be hard to find anything faster other than for special starting conditions.

Comment: `"repeat using the copy as the new original"` - I'm wondering about this part. So your algorithm keeps repeating until no changes are made any more? Do you mean repetition and all takes O(n^4) or the part you are repeating takes that long (if the latter case, I then presume you only run the algorithm once at each time step)? In the prior case, all objects will surely end up being the same.

Comment: I've not read that book, so let me ask, I guess there is only one winner, correct? if so you just need to find the winner (the object with the highest score) and flood the array with the the winner (this would be the end case). Assuming the you don't have the winner already and no quicker method of find the winner in less than `O(n)` then entire process would be `O(n^2)` overall. If you interested in the literal algorithm you described, does the "winner" flood the 4 direction neighbors or the 8 (meaning the diagonals included)? Would you flood the localized winners or the overall ones?

Comment: @SGM1, thanks for the advice, but no, that wouldn't be solve the problem I'm looking to solve (though I might have described it badly!). Objects' scores can change between one "check" and the next - so, although A might beat B now, in a minute (or an hour, or whatever) B might beat A. So we can't simply pick the highest scoring object and flood the array with that. It will flood its 4 neighbours, but behaviour after that is dependent on its future scores.

Comment: @scubbo Oh right, forgot about time dependency. If you have control over the creation of the 2D array, I suggest creating a sorted array along side and start at the **smallest** implement the flood you described. Also, is there a systematic way the score are assigned (meaning like a `+1` or `-1`, if so I'm pretty sure you can do optimization) or is it more so pick a random number from a range each time?

Comment: For reference, you can find an excerpt including a description of the Prison here: http://www.tor.com/stories/2011/05/excerpt-the-quantum-thief-by-hannu-rajaniemi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I'm reading the problem wrong, the obvious solution seems to be:

1. Create a blank array of the same size, call the old array `old` and the new array `new`.
2. For each cell `new[i][j]` in the new array, set it to the maximum of the five possible values: `old[i][j]`, `old[i-1][j]`, `old[i][j-1]`, `old[i+1][j]`, `old[i][j+1]`.
3. `new` is now the updated array for timestep t+1.

Comment: Do this and the sorted array I was talking about a  about earlier and you could slightly optimize (you wouldn't need to check the maximum value objects at all). Also if there is a systematic way the score are assigned (meaning like a +1, +0, or -1) you can do optimization by increasing the number of checks per object relative to their threshold. eg. `6 2 1` the `1` object (1 maximizes to 3) cannot exceed the `6` object (6 minimizes to 4) in 2 steps. Otherwise just does as the algorithm above